# Pthreads are not concurrently operating

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

This is kind of a weird problem so i will do my best to explain. I create two different types of threads in the following manner:

```
    pthread_t *first
    pthread_t *second
    void function(int a, int b){
    first= new pthread_t[a];
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        int *aa = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*aa));
        *aa = i;
        pthread_create(&first[i], NULL, method1, (void *)aa);
    }

    second= new pthread_t[b];
    for(int j = 0; j < b; j++){
        int *bb= (int*)malloc(sizeof(*bb));
        *bb= j;
        pthread_create(&second[i], NULL, method2, (void *)bb);
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < a; k++){
        pthread_join(first[k], NULL);
    }
    for(int l = 0; l < b; l++){
        pthread_join(second[l], NULL);
    }
```

I later have two loops in order to pthread_join from the main thread into the threads contained in both arrays. I also have two simple functions of the same form:

```
    method(void* id){
       write id to file
     }
```

I psuedocode it since I don't find it to be that important, I find the memory management to be the important thing here. I successfully write to the file for both methods (different methods for different type of threads) however no matter what parameters I pass through to the function for a and b, I always print the id of "0" so it looks as though only one thread from each type is actually executing instead of multiple concurrent threads executing.

Can someone help pinpoint the problem? Am I actually running multiple threads and accidentally giving them the same id or is somehow only one thread of each type running and the rest are doing nothing? Is there a way for all the other threads to start running parallel to thread 0?

Thanks.

Comment: Your threads are doing practically nothing. Get them "working up a sweat" if you want to see concurrency.

Comment: Do you join threads later or detach them? Otherwise, they can immediately finish. Also, what is the reason to use `new` with `pthread_t[]`?

Comment: I have them doing more but for debugging purposes the main thing I am doing to check if the threads are operating correctly is by printing the id of the thread to a file. I am essentially working on a solution for the producer-consumer problem using pthreads, however I ran into issues which is why I am simplifying the problem before extending it.

Comment: @karastojko As mentioned in my OP I use two loops for pthread_join to join the main thread with all of the ones I have created. I'll admit that I'm not the most experienced with using pthreads so I'm not sure if that is the right way to go about it.

Comment: Can you please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's hard to say whether joining one thread blocks others or something else is happening.

Comment: @karastojko I added code for joining. I am least confident about this part of my code so if it is blatantly wrong I would really appreciate assistance

Comment: I think you need to show us real code, not pseudo code.  In particular, the contents of method1 and method2.

Comment: look up a pthread_barrier. You can block all threads there until you have constructed everyone, then start them the same time. But if everyone prints the ID 0 there seems to be something else wrong I guess.

Comment: `pthread_create(&second[i], NULL, method2, (void *)bb);` gets as fourth argument the local variable which gets created/destroyed at the end of each loop traverse. Thus, `method()` probably gets a crappy value. Also, I would suggest to use `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int))` instead of `sizeof(*bb)`.

Comment: @karastojko `bb` is created with malloc. It should not get destroyed

Comment: Right. Anyway, I have created an example for which I believe it works like yours, and I have no problems with transferring different ID to each of thread methods and writing them to stdout. So, no clue what is the issue on your side.